# SwiftUI - Get Location and Call Function when App enters Foreground

Tags: swiftui, core-location, combine

I am new to SwiftUI and I am having difficulty with something that I presume is rather simple.
I have created an app that shows the user's current location. If the user puts the app into the background, and the user's physical location changes, the app does not show the new location when it enters the foreground. If I kill the app, then restart, it shows the new location.

I also want to call a function to get an updated dataset from Firebase when the location change is detected. Here is a simplified version of the code that I am using. Please let me know what I am missing. I think I am supposed to use more Combine functionality to achieve this outcome, but I am not sure how?

***My key question is: "How do I detect a location change in my view and call a function as a result of that location change?"***

MyView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {

    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

    var userLatitude: String {
        return "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)"
    }

    var userLongitude: String {
        return "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)"
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("location status: \(locationManager.statusString)")
            HStack {
                Text("latitude: \(userLatitude)")
                Text("longitude: \(userLongitude)")
            }
            Text("place: \(locationManager.placemark?.thoroughfare ?? "")") 
        }
     
    }
    
    func refreshData() {
        // call firebase listener with new location data
    }

}
```

LocationManager.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    @Published var lastLocation: CLLocation? {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    @Published var placemark: CLPlacemark? {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    var statusString: String {
        guard let status = locationStatus else {
            return "unknown"
        }
        
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined: return "notDetermined"
        case .authorizedWhenInUse: return "authorizedWhenInUse"
        case .authorizedAlways: return "authorizedAlways"
        case .restricted: return "restricted"
        case .denied: return "denied"
        default: return "unknown"
        }
        
    }
    
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.locationStatus = status
        print(#function, statusString)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        self.lastLocation = location
        print(#function, location)
        
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            if (error != nil){
                print("Error in reverseGeocode: \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            let placemark = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
            
            if placemark.count > 0 {
                let placemark = placemarks![0]
                self.placemark = placemark
            }
        }
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        if let error = error as? CLError, error.code == .denied {
            // Location updates are not authorized.
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            return
        }
        // Notify the user of any errors.
    }
    
}
```

Comment: did you activate location updates from Signin & Capabilities? (Background Modes)

Comment: Yes, "Location Updates" is checked in "Signing & Capabilities > Background Modes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the lastLocation property inside the LocationManager class to get notified whenever there is a change. With Combine you can achieve that like this:

```
// inside the location manager class
private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = [] // new property to keep track of your subscriptions

// inside the initialiser of the class
$lastLocation
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main) // main thread so view gets an update
    .sink { lastLocation in // subscribe to the published property. Anytime it changes you will get notified
       refreshData()
       // do more with the new value of last location or not :)
    }
    .store(in: cancellabels) // store subscription in property so it doesn’t go out of scope immediately
```

Additionally in your view make sure to bypass the computed properties and subscribe directly to published location property. In my experience computed properties and subscriptions do not work well together.
Inside your text views reference the location coordinates directly:

```
Text(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)
```